# Target "admins" with different styles on the front end

Tags: buddypress, admin-css

I'll first explain what i'm trying to do. I am building an intranet for a client. They do not want employees to be able to edit their profiles or upload avatars, just "admins" should be able to do that. To disable this, i'm going to `display: none` the edit profile and upload avatar buttons by default. I want these to then show for logged in admins -- so they can edit profiles. I didn't see any body class added to logged in admin users, so I was thinking I could add a CSS file for logged in admin users that displayed the hidden div. I am also using WP Engine, I don't know if this is affected by their caching or not.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: if you simply hide the link with css, it does nothing to stop the employee from entering the link directly in the browser ( not to mention that they CAN see it by inspecting the page source )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this:

1. With [template overloads](http://codex.buddypress.org/themes/theme-compatibility-1-7/a-quick-look-at-1-7-theme-compatibility/#overloading-template-compatibility-theme-files)

Overload these files:

> \bp-templates\bp-legacy\buddypress\members\single\profile\edit.php
>
> \bp-templates\bp-legacy\buddypress\members\single\profile\change-avatar

At the top of the overload, do a `current_user_can()` check and then do or don't show the rest of the template.

1. Filter the button creation based on a `current_user_can()` check. See the filter in `bp_get_displayed_user_nav()` in 'bp-members\bp-members-template.php'

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned above in comments, your current approach using CSS will not prevent users from accessing their profile page in the admin area.

You will need to create a custom set of rules using [wordpress roles and capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities).

I grabbed a quick example from [bavotasan.com](http://bavotasan.com/2013/only-allow-administrators-to-access-the-wordpress-admin-area/)

```
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'redirect_non_admin_users' );
/**
 * Redirect non-admin users to home page
 *
 * This function is attached to the 'admin_init' action hook.
 */
function redirect_non_admin_users() {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) && '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' != $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
    }
}
```